# How do I change code of a Single Product page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, product

So I want to add a FAQ under SOME products. Normally I would probably just change the code in the single-product.php. But then I would change every single prodcut page to the same, right?

And since I cant choose different themes for products as you can do with normal pages I dont really know how to do that.

Thank you for reading and I hope that someone can help me! :)

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: thank you @JarrodRoberson but i got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for some of product if you wan to add FAQ then
first list all products id in array

for ex in your single product page

```
$list_of_products = array('1','2','3','4','5');
```

check if you are viewing that product

```
$current_product = $product->id;
if(in_array($current_product,$list_of_products))
{
      //do something here (add FAQ block or html)
}
```

if you have different FAQ's
then use if else if instead of if condition

Comment: thank you so much!
Which file do I write that in?
In single-products.php?

Comment: yes in single-product.php of your activated theme

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom fields to your product when you are adding using "Advance custom fields" or some other plugin. If you are good in WP you can write your own custom field and update the FAQ in that custom fields.